# XML Sitemap : broken XML file

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I use WP SEO by Yoast to generate sitemaps and the sitemap generated for custom types has a short hexa string at the beginning that invalidate the whole XML file :

```
148e2
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="//cabouge.tv5monde.com/main-sitemap.xsl"?>
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

<del>You can see the live file here</del> (problem solved on the live file).

The characters at the beginning of the files seams to be linked to the content, because they are different for another custom type.

I use WPSEO v1.5.2.5, but the bug was present with version 1.4.6.
It seams to be linked to my server configuration, because I cannot reproduce it on a testing server with the same Wordpress code installed on it. The production server runs PHP 5.3.8.

I tried to disable all other plugins, but the issue is still present.

Any idea about where I could find the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seams to be an issue with the `header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK')` function call in Yoast's Wordpress SEO plugin that is not compatible with my server configuration (Nginx with some security config in front, then apache for php processing).

In some way I do not fully understand, this php function call was forcing the server to send an HTTP/1.1 header with a HTTP/1.0 encoded body, so the end of the response header was interpreted as the beginning of the body.

Checkout [the issue I have created on wordpress-seo github repo](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/issues/983) for more information.